# Variable initialization in different translation unit

Tags: c++, initialization

Suppose we have two translation units:

```
//--a.cpp--//

int a;
int b; 
int c;

int main(){ }

//--b.cpp--//


int d;
int e;
int f;
```

That program does not start a thread. Hence (3.6.2/2)

> the initialization of a variable is indeterminately sequenced with
>   respect to the initialization of a variable defined in a different
>   translation unit.

Does it mean that only after initialization of all variables in a translation unit (e.g. `b.cpp`), implementation starts to initialize variable in another translation unit (`a.cpp`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialization of globals in a translation unit is in definition order, so `a, b, c` and `d, e, f`.

But it is unspecified if it is `a, b, c` and then `d, e, f` or if it is the other way around.

Or even in interlaved order (say, `a, d, b, c, e, f`), although I think that most implementations will initialize all the global variables from a translation unit in a single row, so other than in multithreading, I don't think that will happen in practice.

Comment: Why can't the initialization be interleaved like `a, d, b, c, e, f`?

Comment: @dyp: I reckon that that is explicitly allowed by the standard. But other than multithreading I don't see any reason an implementation would do that. I'll add it to the answer, anyway.

Comment: When the program spawns another thread, the initialization is unsequenced. *indeterminately sequenced* would required some synchronisation mechanism if multiple threads concurrently initialized variables in different TUs.

Comment: In fact, I have looked for `a, d, b, c, e, f` like example. Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

No, indeterminately sequenced means that they occur in some order but that order is not specified. The variables in one translation unit will be initialized either before or after the variables in the other.

Comment: Do you imply the whole set of initializations in one TU is done completely either before or after the whole set of initializations in another TU? See my comments to / and rodrigo's answer.